# Getting system language UWP C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

I wanted to get the system language (not the input language, but the overall system language) in the C++/WinRT app, but can't find a way for doing such. I googled and found that in `Unity` this can be done using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` structure, which is not available in C++ code. Anybody's familiar with this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a Windows Runtime type, but since you are using C++, you can simply call into [GetLocaleInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Getting system language UWP C++/WinRT

You can use the [Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.language?view=winrt-19041) Class to get the system language. First, you need to include the header files it needs. For example:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.System.UserProfile.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Globalization.h>

void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    auto topUserLaunghage = Windows::System::UserProfile::GlobalizationPreferences::Languages().GetAt(0);
    Windows::Globalization::Language language{topUserLaunghage};
    hstring displayName = language.DisplayName();
}
```

**Update:**

When you change the Regional format, the date, time, etc will change its format, you could get the language that was most recently used to format dates and times by using [ResolvedLanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.resolvedlanguage?view=winrt-19041) of DateTimeFormatter. For example:

```
Windows::Globalization::GeographicRegion userRegion{};
hstring regionCode = userRegion.CodeTwoLetter();
Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<hstring> coll{ winrt::single_threaded_vector<hstring>() };
coll.Append(regionCode);
auto dateTimeFormatter = Windows::Globalization::DateTimeFormatting::DateTimeFormatter(L"longdate", coll);
auto regionInfoName = dateTimeFormatter.ResolvedLanguage(); // This is the language from the Regional format
```

Comment: I have already seen this on MSDN. The thing is, on the first line, it gets the input language of the user or system, but not the UI language. What I want is to get the system UI language

Comment: Are you referring to the UI language which can be set by an administrator in the Welcome screen and new user accounts settings? Do you want to get the Display language of Welcome screen?

Comment: Settings > Time & Language > Region > Regional format (isn't this the UI language?)

Comment: For Unity, as I said, the parameter holds this exact property set on the system

Comment: I have found out that I no longer need the answer of this question, but any way will accept it if anybody else needs the solution. Thanks for the info.